# Site style: bold text is not distinguishable from normal text

Tags: bug, status-declined, design

I'm trying to **replicate** (this was supposed to be **bold**) the problem here.

Browser: Firefox 17.0.6 ESR.

- **bold** (**doesn't work**)
- normal
- *italic* (works)

[image: Screenshot]

That's how **bold** shows up on Unix SE:
[image: Unix Screenshot]

Update: turns out it is a Firefox 17 issue, and isn't replicated on other browsers. Can be closed.

Comment: Bold works fine for me (on Chrome). Could you add a screenshot so we have a better idea of what you are seeing?

Comment: Works Fine on Firefox 21.0 and 22.0 on Mac OS X even with JS turned off.

Comment: Does bold outside of lists work?

Comment: Downloading 17.0.7 ESR to bughunt.

Comment: @WorldEngineer - **bold** doesn't work in comments, neither does it in the question text. (Hint: word **bold** is in **bold**). Thanks for the prompt reply.

Comment: @DeerHunter is there any possibility you have any javascript issues going on? (I'm not aware if the bold effect is applied to the markup from the server, or by javascript on the client; in the case of the ladder you may have a broken-state in your browser right now)

Comment: http://i.stack.imgur.com/oy8KV.png - Doesn't appear to be anything wrong there... What OS are you using? Your fonts look "off". @JimmyHoffa It's not JS. I tested with JS blocked. No effect.

Comment: @WorldEngineer - CentOS 6.4. Firebug shows nothing unusual, I've tried a test comment on Unix & Linux SE, it shows bold.

Comment: @WorldEngineer - posted a shot from another SE site.

Comment: I vote the image is photoshopped... heh

Comment: @JimmyHoffa - software used: `KolourPaint`.

Comment: @DeerHunter have you tried chrome to see if you get bold there? If not I'd be curious to see a screenshot of your font selection from chromes debugger tools. There's a failback path of fonts for when X isn't found on your machine, it'll try Y, then Z, et al, chrome's debugging tools will make clear which fonts it failed to find and which one it ended up using in place. It may have failed back to a particular font which your system doesn't have a bold form installed for. To see these details, right click the text in Chrome and select "Inspect element" you'll see render details on the right

Comment: @JimmyHoffa - No Chrome here, will try with GTK WebKit in a few hours.

Comment: I'm afraid the answer will be that Firefox 17.0.6 is not supported. SE generally tries to support the current and immediately previous stable versions of major browsers, and 17.0.6 is a bit old (21 is the current stable).

Comment: 22.0 is the current stable, it updated today.

Comment: Okay, you can consider it not a problem then. Having CentOS, I'm a bit behind the cutting edge.

Comment: Confirmed to be browser-specific. Can be closed.